# How to check if the first char in the line is # (beginning of a comment)

Tags: c++, stl

I have been following this convention thus far:

```
std::string line;
while(std::getline(in,line)) 
{
    if(line.size() && line[0] =='#')
      continue;
    /* parse text*/
}
```

The obvious drawback is that comment may not begin at the first character, in the case of leading whitespace.

What is the good way to deal with this sort of a thing?

Comment: Can you post an example of the file you are parsing?

Comment: it just a bunch of columns with numbers. I just want to put some text to denote what columns mean, as well as other general comments.

Comment: Don't worry about cases where comment comes on the same line as numbers

Comment: Use the operator >> to skip white space. See Below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simple enhancement: you may want to use line.find_first_not_of(" ") to get the first non-whitespace and then check if *that* is a '#'. That would also cover to the zero length case. Something like this fragment:

```
  found= line.find_first_not_of(" \t");

  if( found != string::npos)
  {
    if( line[found] == '#')
      continue;
  }
```

[More info](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_not_of/)

Comment: This seem to be a portable solution. Someone suggested using in>>std::wc to skip white spaces. While it is visually appealing, it didn't work in my environment.

Comment: Those are not the only white space characters. There are a couple more in ASCII and if your input is UTF-8 there are a whole bunch more. You should use the standard white space skipping mechanism to make sure it works in all environments.

Answer (score 3):

Use the operator >>. It ignores whitespace.

```
std::string line;
while(std::getline(in,line))
{
    std::stringstream linestr(line);
    char              firstNoWhiteSpaceChar;

    linestr >> firstNoWhiteSpaceChar;
    if ((!linestr) || (firstNoWhiteSpaceChar == '#')) 
    {
        // If line contains only white space then linestr will become invalid.
        // As the equivalent of EOF is set. This is the same as a comment so
        // we can ignore the line like a comment.
        continue;
    }

    // Do Stuff with line.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure to check the string length before testing character zero:

```
if (line.length() > 0 && line[0] == '#')
```

Comment: This is a good & needed check to avoid indexing outside the string, but won't handle leading whitespace.

Comment: isn't line.empty()  better? Meyers recommends empty() as opposed to length(). BTW, I do this check in the actual code

Comment: If you do this check, why wouldn't you put it in your original post?

Comment: empty() is better if you are only testing the first character, yes.

Answer (score 1):

From the sound of things, your file format specifies that everything from '#' to the end of a line is a comment. If that's the case, you can find the beginning of the comment with:

```
// Warning: untested code.
int pos = line.find('#');
```

Then, you presumably want to ignore the rest of the line, most easily managed by deleting it:

```
if (pos != std::string::npos)
    line.erase(pos, -1);
```

This should deal quite easily with things like:

```
tax = rate * price    # figure tax on item
```

Of course, this assumes that a '#' *always* signals the beginning of a comment -- if you allow '#' inside of characters strings, or for whatever other purpose, you'll need to take that into account (but it's hard to guess what that would be since you've told us very little about the file format).

Answer (score 1):

Use the stream's facility to skip whitespace, `std::ws`:

```
inline std::istream& get_line(std::istream& in, std::string& line)
{
    in >> std::ws;
    std::getline(in,line);
    return in;
}

std::string line;
while(get_line(in,line)) 
{
    if(!line.empty() && line[0] =='#')
        continue;
    /* parse text*/
}
```

Comment: This seems to be GCC-specific, though it would be nice for other compilers/library vecdors as well.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what "doesn't work" means and why you think it's "GCC-specific"? I pasted the above into a VS test project, compiled it, and checked it with a few test lines. It seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You might like the [Boost String Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/string_algo.html), specifically `trim_left` and `starts_with`.

Comment: Why on earth not? C++ without boost is C++ how it should be (and in many areas, will be shortly with 0x).

Comment: Er, make that "is" and "isn't" :)

Comment: Introducing Boost can be an immense challenge, verging on impossible in a corporate environment. It's no different to using any third party library whether it will end up in 0x or not. It needs installing and maintaining across team(s) and could take months to get approval... I love and use Boost but I wouldn't install Boost just to solve this.

Comment: @Adam Wright you must have not worked with a legacy code or in a corp. that mandates certain rules and regulations. I wish I could use boost :) though

Comment: @Stuart alas, exactly how I feel!

Comment: @Stuart: No, boost is unlike many other libraries. With only some very few exceptions, boost is all headers. This means that you can usually just check it in besides your project and be done.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing is tricky and difficult.

In general, I would not recommend trying to parse without a state machine. For example, what if the '#' is part of a multiline ("""...""" in python) ?

There are libraries that exist which may simplify parsing (well, they are supposed to, but understanding them might prove challenging if you have no prior inkling), for example, in C++, one can only recommend [Spirit](http://spirit.sourceforge.net/).

There are already been some pointers suggested to help you using string methods, though they only related to detecting if the first meaningful character is a '#'.

If you do not 'fear' multiline (that is if what you are trying to parse does not have such a feature), you will still have to manage 'simple' lines, which can be done by counting, taking escapes into account:

```
print "My \"#\" is: ", phoneNumber # This is my phone number
```

If you parse this line badly, you'll end up with an error... (for example)

If you cannot use a library, a state machine is the way to go, writing a parser is quite fun in general, it gives you insights as to why the notation has been developed in a certain way.

Comment: No need to go crazy, my requirements are much simpler!

Comment: Most languages do not support multi-line strings.

Comment: @Martin: true, though they might have streaming comments in exchange. I was just trying to attract the attention of Andrei so that he would provide more context on the file format.